# Revert issue using the safe-eth-py package because Invalid Owner

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

Regarding this method in safe-eth-py package
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py/blob/master/gnosis/safe/safe.py#L1113

Is there any limitations in size in the data parameter?
We are experiencing that sometimes depending on how big the data field is transactions that are sent from the relayer throw an Exception of  `InvalidOwner`  but this is quite misleading because it only happens on those situtations when this field is quite big but in other it's fine (always using the same from and to)

Another thing that we encountered while using this same package is that some of the "revert" messages were not parsed/decoded

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/web3/_utils/method_formatters.py#L626
GitHub

Changing that line from "Revert" to revert helped us to see the issue - so we were wondering if it has something to do when to this error that happend a while ago https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py/issues/26  (see the message about the revert)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any limitations in size in the data parameter?

No that we are aware. Usually `InvalidOwner` pops up when `signature` is not valid, so either because a wrong signer is used or a wrong `safeTxHash` is signed. In our experience it happens a lot when signing a tx with a wrong nonce (in the future or already executed). If you can find a concrete case that's failing please create a PR with all the data and we will check it.

> Changing that line from "Revert" to revert helped us to see the issue

Reverts were not really easy to handle, as depending on the nodes different errors were returned. I think that's better now. We encourage in this case to go to web3.py team as we did, as we are relying on their implementation: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1888